# How to Align Two Fields Horizontally in Android Programatically

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I was Programmatically  Creating Linear Layout and I want to Align two Fields on same Line. But i Want to display the result as like expected.

```
 lView = new LinearLayout(Main2Activity.this);
                   // lView.setPadding(0,150,0,0);
                    lView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EDFCFC"));
                    lView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    Button logout = new Button(Main2Activity.this);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    logout.setLayoutParams(params);
                    logout.setText("Logout");


                    logout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F53F37"));
                    lView.addView(logout);
TextView title = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
                    title.setText("ASSOCIATES");
                    title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2BD865"));
                    title.setTextSize(25);
                    title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    lView.addView(title);


                    TextView title1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
                    title1.setText("Date :");
                    title1.setTextSize(20);
                    lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    lView.addView(title1);


                    et1 = new EditText(Main2Activity.this);
                    et1.setWidth(10);
                    et1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    et1.setHint("Date");
                    //lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                    lView.addView(et1);
```

My Actual Output is

[image]

Expected
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set gravity for your parent `LinearLayout` to align childs.

Answer (score 0):

set the Linear Layout orientation to horizontal like this:

```
                lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Here,
You need to set gravity of layout so you can display all child view at single line.
You have to apply android:gravity="center_vertical" for your linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add LayoutParams to your `textview` and `edittext` and you will get the specified view.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

TextView title1 = new TextView(Main2Activity.this);
title1.setLayoutParams(params);
title1.setText("Date :");
title1.setTextSize(20);
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
lView.addView(title1);
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

et1 = new EditText(Main2Activity.this);
et1.setLayoutParams(params);
et1.setWidth(10);
et1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
et1.setHint("Date");
lView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
lView.addView(et1);
```

Comment: i used your code but it is aligning one by one on left side.

Comment: i am getting error on setGravity...i too have updated my code full code

Comment: it is aligned one by one in center

Comment: Check the code. And you have to update the gravity according to your requirement

Comment: it is displaying one by one only. it is not coming in one row.

Comment: change the orientation of your linear layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132800/discussion-between-karthick-anbazhagan-and-anjali).